# Hadoop JUnit testing writing/reading to/from the hdfs

Tags: junit, hadoop, hdfs

I have written a class(es) that writes and reads from hdfs.  Given certain conditions that are occurring when these classes are instantiated they create a specific path and file, and write to it (or they go to a previously created path and file and read from it).  I have tested it by running a few hadoop jobs, and it appears to be functioning correctly.

However, I would like to be able to test this in the JUnit framework, but I have not found a good solution for being able to test reading and writing to hdfs in JUnit.  I would appreciate an helpful advice on the matter.  Thanks.

Comment: do you have a tiny bit of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself yet, but I believe what you are looking for is org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.

It is in hadoop-test-.jar NOT hadoop-core-.jar.  I guess the Hadoop project uses it internally to test.

Here it is:

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/hdfs/trunk/src/test/hdfs/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/MiniDFSCluster.java?revision=1127823&view=markup&pathrev=1130381

I think there are plenty of uses of it in that same directory, but here is one:

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/hdfs/trunk/src/test/hdfs/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/TestWriteRead.java?revision=1130381&view=markup&pathrev=1130381